# Runtime error 2465: Can't find the field "|1" referenced

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I inherited this Access Database for a client and was tasked with updating some things in it. Unfortunately I don't know much about VBA/Access. I keep receiving the error `Runtime error 2465: Can't find the field "|1" referenced` on the `DoCmd.SendObject` line. I've done a lot of searching and it's such a cryptic error I'm getting nowhere. Can someone explain to me what is wrong here? I'm assuming it's a syntax issue somewhere or I'm using variables wrong or something.

```
Private Sub cbCompleted_AfterUpdate()

    If cbCompleted = -1 Then
        tbCompleted = Date
        tbCompleted.Locked = True
        Doctor_Name.Locked = True
        Department.Locked = True
        Start_Date.Locked = True
        Specialty.Locked = True
        Doctor_.Locked = True
        Taxonomy_.Locked = True
        DepartmentCombo.Locked = True
        UPIN_.Locked = True
        SpecialtyCombo.Locked = True
        Dim sd As String
        Dim dn As String
        sd = "" & [Start Date]
        dn = "" & [Doctor Name]
        DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , "Tim,Keith,Yvonne,Sandy,susan@domain.org,Vicki@domain.org", "Tom,Barbara,Rachael,Penny,Troy,bernasue@domain.org", , "Doctor " & dn & " " & "Start Date:" & " " & sd, dn & " " & "is scheduled to start" & sd & vbNewLine & "NPI# :" & [NPI#] & vbNewLine & "Specialty: " & [Speciality#] & vbNewLine & "Department/Practice: " & [Department#] & vbNewLine & "Provider# for HR/Acctg: " & [Doctor#], True


    Else
        '[snip] Unlock all fields locked above
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks much

Comment: Was this ever working or? It seems as though the lists of strings need to be separated by `;` and not `,`. Did you try that? It can be found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197046(v=office.15).aspx). A good troubleshooting technique would be to delete some arguments in your `DoCmd.SendObject` to identify what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: It was working as far as not producing an error. However the variables in the email body were not showing up.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter on the previous comment. [cont] I then began simplifying the arguments and rebuilding the line one variable/argument at a time. And discovered I had typoed `Specialty#` as `Speciality#` and it now works. I can't believe it was so simple.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work.